# Script to Download Zipped Google Drive Folder

Tags: google-drive-api, backup, storage

In Google Drive it is possible to right click a folder and download as a zip with all files converted to MS Office, jpegs and so on.

What I am looking for is way of doing this automatically everyday, whether it be through a 3rd Party application or writing a script myself.

Any direction/solution would be great thanks.